# How to reference outside Contexts in test files?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm really struggling to understand Contexts in Phoenix Elixir. I have three contexts, `Auth` (contains `User.ex`), `Groups` (`Circle.ex`), and `Content` (`ShareMark.ex`). Within each of those, there are schemas, `users`, `circles`, and `sharemarks` respectively.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the pre-provided `create_circle` outside of the `Groups` context. Is there something a context is analogous to in Ruby?

Within `content_test.ex`, I am trying to define the following

`@valid_attrs %{circle: Groups.create_circle(%{name: "My test"}), url: "google.com", title: "Google"}`

```ex
defmodule ShareMark.ContentTest do
  use ShareMark.DataCase

  alias ShareMark.Content
  use ShareMark.Groups
  describe "sharemarks" do
    alias ShareMark.Content.ShareMark
    @valid_attrs %{circle: Groups.create_circle(%{name: "Evan's test"}), url: "google.com", title: "Google"}
    @update_attrs %{circle: Groups.create_circle(%{name: "Mike's test"}), url: "duckduckgo.com", title: "DuckDuckGo"}
    @invalid_attrs %{circle: Groups.create_circle(%{name: "Bad test"})}

    def sharemark_fixture(attrs \\ %{}) do
      {:ok, sharemark} =
        attrs
        |> Enum.into(@valid_attrs)
        |> Content.create_sharemark()

      sharemark
    end
 ...
end
```

Here is `circle.ex`

```ex
defmodule ShareMark.Groups.Circle do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "circles" do
    field :name, :string
    field :creator_id, :id
    many_to_many :members, ShareMark.Auth.User, join_through: "users_circles"
    has_many :sharemarks, ShareMark.Content.ShareMark

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(circle, attrs) do
    circle
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

But it is giving the following error:

```ex
** (CompileError) test/sharemark/content/content_test.exs:8: undefined function create_circle/1
```

Google is completely unhelpful, as Phoenix has so few questions asked about it. Sorry for such a novice question.

Comment: Does the `Groups.create_circle` method by any chance interact with the database?

Comment: It does it does. It creates a circle and adds it to the DB. `|> Repo.insert()`

Answer (score 2):

In your test you have this line:

```
use ShareMark.Groups
```

this should be an `alias` statement:

```
alias ShareMark.Groups
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) does not force you to use *Contexts*, they're just a way of better organizing your code. This makes them slightly more confusing for beginners, compared to the *File-Type First (FTF)* structure of [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) applications, but makes the code heirarchy much more easier to understand and manage in the long haul.

**You can choose to use contexts or just put all modules together.** Either way, whatever public functions you define are acessible from anywhere else in the app (*as long as you use the correct module name to call them*).

More resources on Contexts:

- Youtube: [Chris McCord on Contexts](https://youtu.be/tMO28ar0lW8?t=680)
- Hexdocs: [Phoenix Contexts](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html)
- Blog Post: [Organizing Large React Apps](http://engineering.kapost.com/2016/01/organizing-large-react-applications/)
  <sub>*(Not about Elixir, but still a good overview)*</sub>

---

Now on to your actual code, there are *two problems* with it.

**First, as @Paweł mentioned, you need to `alias` your module or use the full name:**

```
alias ShareMark.Groups
```

---

**Second, you're calling `Groups.create_circle` in a [module attribute](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html)** (`@value`). Module attributes aren't like your regular "variables", [they are resolved at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862889/elixir-modifying-value-of-module-attribute?rq=1). Meaning, in your case, they will try to write to the database before you even start your test suite.

To fix that, either move your initialization logic to your actual test or into ExUnit's [`setup/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup/1) callback:

```ex
setup do
  %{circle: Groups.create_circle(%{name: "Test Circle"}}
end

test "something", %{circle: circle} do
  valid_attrs = %{circle: circle, url: "google.com", title: "Google"}
  # assert something
end
```

Comment: Wonderful. Answers like these are why Stack Overflow is so great. You've given me the answer to my question, and more useful resources so I don't have to keep coming back. Thanks!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.